# How to load file on AgensGraph?

Tags: agens-graph

I tried to load comma separated file on agensgraph.

But agensgraph does not have load utility on package.

How can I load file on agensgraph?

Answer (score 0):

You can use "Foreign Data Wrapper", Instead of utility.

First, create file few extension.

```
agens=# CREATE EXTENSION file_fdw;
CREATE EXTENSION
```

Second, create server object.

```
agens =# CREATE SERVER graph_import FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER file_fdw;
CREATE SERVER
```

Next, create foreign table with file.

```
agens =# CREATE FOREIGN TABLE fdwSample
agens-# (
agens(#         id INT8,
agens(#         name VARCHAR(256)
agens(# )
agens-# SERVER graph_import
agens-# OPTIONS
agens-# (
agens(#          FORMAT 'csv',
agens(#          HEADER 'false',
agens(#          DELIMITER ',',
agens(#          NULL '',
agens(#          FILENAME 'sample.dat'
agens(# );
CREATE FOREIGN TABLE
```

Last, load file use "LOAD" clause.

```
agens=# LOAD FROM fdwSample AS sample
agens-# CREATE (:node {id:sample.id,name:sample.name});
GRAPH WRITE (INSERT VERTEX 2, INSERT EDGE 0)
```

After all, you can find loaded data.

```
agens =# MATCH (n:node) RETURN n;
                  n                  
-------------------------------------
 node[3.1]{"id": 1, "name": "steve"}
 node[3.2]{"id": 2, "name": "bill"}
(2 rows)
```

Good luck.